# Migrating from HSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, grails, migration, hsqldb, data-migration

I see a lot of questions about moving from MySQL to HSQL but none about doing the reverse.

I have the .script file, and everything else. I just need to cleanly import that into a MySQL database. There is no binary data or other issues. Extracting MySQL compatible create / insert statements would be fine (and preferred!).